# wordpress index of cgi-bin (not the whole list of files though)

Tags: centos, wordpress, cgi-bin

I have setup a few wordpress with centos, apache in the same server and they all works fine.  But somehow this is with this wordpress, when I go to the `domain.com` it just shows

```
Index of /
    Name    Last modified   Size    Description
    cgi-bin/    2020-07-20 12:53    -
```

I googled but everyone's answer is either because there's a subdirectory installed by accident which it's not though.  Also this is  not installed through a cpanel.

this is how my root directory of the wordpress looks like

```
drwxr-xr-x.  5 apache apache  4096 Sep 28 02:58 .
drwxr-xr-x. 17 apache apache  4096 Sep 27 20:25 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache    19 Sep 14  2018 3f361b82411a33ef76.txt
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache    16 Sep 14  2018 1D3AE47DEBA.html
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache   418 Sep 14  2018 index.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache 19935 Sep 14  2018 license.txt
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  7415 Jun 11 00:34 readme.html
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  6878 Apr 30 00:34 wp-activate.php
drwxrwxrwx.  9 apache apache  4096 Sep 14  2018 wp-admin
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache   364 Sep 14  2018 wp-blog-header.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  1889 Sep 14  2018 wp-comments-post.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  3312 Sep 14  2018 wp-config.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  2853 Sep 14  2018 wp-config-sample.php
drwxrwxrwx.  7 apache apache  4096 Sep 28 02:57 wp-content
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  3669 Sep 14  2018 wp-cron.php
drwxrwxrwx. 18 apache apache 12288 Sep 14  2018 wp-includes
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  2422 Sep 14  2018 wp-links-opml.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  3306 Sep 14  2018 wp-load.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache 37804 Apr 30 00:34 wp-login.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  8048 Sep 14  2018 wp-mail.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache 16246 Sep 14  2018 wp-settings.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache 30091 Sep 14  2018 wp-signup.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  4620 Sep 14  2018 wp-trackback.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  3065 Sep 14  2018 xmlrpc.php
```

I even seen posts about changing the `httpd.conf` file

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex  index.php index.html
</IfModule>
```

actually the above is already there.

This is how my virtualhost looks like which is copied then modified the directory and servername from other working wordpress

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/lci
    <Directory "/var/www/lci">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What might be the possibility of any settings I might have forgotten?

If I click into the `cgi-bin` like I get a 403 forbidden though.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and advices

Comment: Hm, OK. Did Apache restart successfully with this configuration? What directory did you provide a listing of? Is PHP installed?

Comment: @MichaelHampton 1. Apache restarted fine without any error, the directory is the one I put in the virtual host config above `/var/www/lci` and that directory contain the list I provided with 2nd screenshot.  For sure php is installed as php72 and as mentioned, the same server has few other wordpress projects too all running fine within their own directory

Comment: Do you have more than one VirtualHost for that domain? Do you get a redirect when you request that domain?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider that domain is only for that  domain in one virtuallhost....therre's no  same virualhost with the same domain

Comment: Do you see the requests in the Apache log? Is the domain resolving to the correct IP address?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I do not see anything logged for this domain though.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I was looking at the log here `/var/log/httpd/access_log` should be looking at the correct place?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider omg you gave me an idea that what if the other developer did not setup dns correctly because I just pinged the site the ip returned doesn't seem correct omg if this is the reason I will *arg*